# Commonly concepts in adding contacts for staffs using master table

Tags: sql

Using MS SQL: The scenario is I have already a Contact master table (tbl_Customer)for all contacts in the company. The staffs suggested that they do not want to see all the contact and that they will only choose which contacts are applicable for them. The contact table is not gonna be store on the client like an outlook's pst file but on server side particularly on the database.

The methods i can use are:

1.) every time i add a staff i create a new independent table for the staff and the staff just adds the contact he/she needs from the master table via a program.

2.) I can change the contact master table to add say 50 fields with names staff01, staff02 and so on... I will make use of this fields as a marker that this rows of customer is a contact of the staff on the fields.

3.) I do a completely new contact list. Adds a field name "User". Mark the initial records via putting "ALL" on the field name. If a staff adds a contact, the table add a record with his/her name on the field "User". There will be an Auto numbered field as primary index.

Currently I'm tempted to use 3.) are there any other better method for my problem?

Comment: If you want to use a DBMS (like SQL-Server), my suggestion is to start reading on the [Relational Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) and [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). The link is just a reference, not an easy read. There are a lot of good books and sites about Relational databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you have a staff table with a staff id - then every contact the staff in question wants can be a row in staffContacts. Column 1 is staffID and col 2 is contactID. Then you can join on the contact table to retrieve the details you want.

The contacts table then only needs be updated...You only need to add one table with two columns. You may wish to impose constraints that let fields be entered that are unique to staffID and contact ID and are valid staff members and contacts. 
Nick.

Comment: I already have a staff table. you mean i'll make a new table to connect the staff and customer table? I think that solves my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes - the new table is literally two columns of ids. StaffID,ContactID. For each StaffID there could be many ContactIDs. Join the ContactID to the contacts table for a given StaffID.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to have a list of the contacts that is filtered specifically based on a particular users preferences?

Personally I would create another table like this:

```
Create Table UserContactPreferences
(
ID int identity(1,1),
UserID int,
ContactID int,
)
```

And then each individual user can pick what contacts they want visible and you can add an entry here for it.

Then when you query the database you can do something like this, passing in the CurrentUser in the query:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM tbl_Customer c
JOIN UserContactPreferences up on c.contactID = up.contactID
WHERE up.UserID = @CurrentUser
```

This will then only return Customers that the user has specifically said they want to see.

Answer (score 0):

In case many staff members have the same relevant contact - you should use a connection table, in which there will be 2 columns - one with the contact id , and one with the staff member id, use this table to query for staff's relevant contacts.

In case each contact has only one staff, than simply add a column with the relevant staff id, which will be a foreign key to the staff's table.

In any case and for other users to learn from:

**method 1** you suggested is a big no no in SQL DB design, you need a really good reason for a DB with dynamically created tables.

**method 2** is bad practice since most of the space will be wasted (unless defined as sparse columns but even though.. still space consuming) and also too specific - what will happen when you add a new staff member ? add a new column ? lock the whole DB for it and add many wasted space allocated?